# netbeans - plugins require HTML Editor Library to be installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, ubuntu

I am attempting set up Netbeans 7.1 as my RoR editor.  When trying to install plugins I get the following error:

> Some plugins require plugin HTML Editor Library to be installed. The
>   plugin HTML Editor Library is requested in version >= 1.21 (release
>   version 1) but only 2.0.1 (of release version different from 1) was
>   found.  The following plugin is affected:       
>   Embedded Ruby (RHTML)

I looked for this HTML plugin so I could install it but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the Ruby on Rails plugin has some problem (i.e. does not support) Netbeans 7.1 and 7.2. But it works with version 6.9 and 7.

Reference: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38549/ruby-and-rails

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong this is the lovely 207075 from the bugtracker: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=207075

In fact there's a workaround for this issue:
http://blog.enebo.com/2012/01/workaround-for-ruby-support-on-netbeans.html

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install it on a newly downloaded Netbeans (7.1 in my case), you should first go to Tools > Plugins, select Updates Tab and install the updates. Then, after restart, you'll go to the mentioned above Plugins, and now you will able to install all the required updates (HTML Editor will be among them.)

Lastl thing, as @skripted already mentioned, just install the plugin by following the [instructions on this page](http://blog.enebo.com/2012/01/workaround-for-ruby-support-on-netbeans.html).